# What's the time complexity of this while loop?

Tags: c, while-loop, time-complexity

```
while(n>x) 
  x*=x;
```

The correct answer is log(log(n)), I can see the log(n) since x^k>=n is when the while loop will stop. so I got to log(n), what am I missing?

P.S: it is given that x=2.

Comment: Worst-case complexity is `O(infinite)` if that's even a thing (when `x <= 1`)

Comment: It will be `log(n)` in case `x *= c` (where `c` is some *constant* value)

Comment: @tkausl O(infinite) is not a thing, and not supposing that x>1 is a precondition makes the whole thing "not an algorithm" in the first place

Answer (score 5):

Let a be the original value of x, and assume a>1.

- After the first cycle, x=a**2
- After the second cycle, x=a**4
- After the third cycle, x=a**8
- ... After the k-th cycle, x = a**(2**k)

x >= n means

```
a**(2**k) >= n
2**k >= log(n)/log(a)
k >= log2(log(n)/log(a)) = log2(log(n))-log2(log(a))
```

Answer (score 4):

Expand the loop (let `x = 2`) and you'll see:

```
  x =     2 
  x =     4 //   2 * 2
  x =    16 //   4 * 4
  x =   256 //  16 * 16 
  x = 65536 // 256 * 256
  ... 
  x = 2 ** (2 ** n) // you can prove this by induction
```

and so

```
  n = log(log(x))
```

you'll be quite right with `n = log(x)` estimation if you have `x *= constant` body, e.g. for the `constant == 2` we have

```
  x = 2
  x = 4
  x = 8
  ...
  x == 2 ** n
```

where `n` is just

```
  n = log(x)
```

Answer (score 3):

Let `x` starting value be `a`, `> 1`. Each time the value of `x` is an exponential of `a`, and the exponential *doubles* each time, as you are squaring the number each iteration.

So the `m`'th term is given by [image], where `m` is the number of loops executed. Therefore we need [image], or [image], which is indeed [image].

Answer (score 0):

Edit: `(Given x = 2)`

Your answer would be correct if:

```
while(n>x) 
  x*=2;
```

This means the time to reach the result is **cut into half every iteration**.

But since the time is cut by `x` every iteration and `x` is increasing, you'll get `O log(Log(n))`.

`Log(n)` is the complexity where you skip half the way every iteration (B-Tree).